# How to wrap an absolute position container as any other relative positioned div?

Tags: css, typescript, vuetify.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I am using ag-grid to display paginated data in a vuetify layout.

For some reasons it seems that when one of the parents of the ag-grid component is `flex` and `paginationAutoPageSize` is set to `true` then the grid keeps on adding new lines repeatedly (clearly a bug).

https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/628#issuecomment-440216606

[image]

Adding that class below to the ag-grid component:

```
.ag-grid-16 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

gives then:

[image]

Which is better but sadly does not work out very well with the rest of the Vuetify layout in my application (the Cashout title and the horizontal line are both covered by the component).

The grid itself:

`CashoutRecords.vue`:

```
<template>
    <ag-grid-vue
        class="ag-theme-material gray-border ag-grid-16"
        :columnDefs="columnDefs"
        :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
        :frameworkComponents="frameworkComponents"
        :rowData="cashoutRecords"
        :gridOptions="gridOptions"
        :paginationAutoPageSize="true"
        :pagination="true"
        :enableRangeSelection="true"
        @grid-ready="onGridReady"
    ></ag-grid-vue>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .ag-row .ag-cell {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .ag-grid-16 {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
  }

  .white-bg {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

  .light-bg {
    background-color: #fdfefe;
  }

  .gray-border {
    border-color: lightgray;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
  }
</style>

<script lang="ts" src="./CashoutRecords.ts">
</script>
```

and its container:

`Cashout.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-container>

    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <h1 class="display-1">Cashouts</h1>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="auto">
        <v-btn color="info" @click="openEditModal = true">
          New <v-icon small right>create</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <hr class="divider__full" />

    <CashoutRecords />

    <CashoutEditModal :open.sync="openEditModal" />

  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts" src="./Cashout.ts">
</script>
```

How can I wrap my ag-grid with that `ag-grid-16` CSS class (in order to avoid the evergrowing rows) in a way that I can still see the `<h1>` title `Cashouts` and the horizontal line above it.